# mysql subtract the sum of all rows from the first row

Tags: mysql

if i have the following data

```
index | value1 | value2 | value3 |...
  1   |  100   |   200  |   300  |...
  2   |   6    |    30  |    12  |...
  3   |   23   |    11  |    22  |...
....
```

There are 150 columns in total, and there will be LOTS row as well. What would the best way be to get the sum of all the rows except index = 1 and subtract the sum from index1's row.

```
ie: 
value1 = 100-6-23-...-...-...
value2 = 200-30-11-...-...-...
value3 = 300-12-22-...-...-...
....
```

is there any good mysql queries that allow me to do such thing

Comment: 150 columns *can* be symptomatic of poor design

Comment: In this instance, it almost certainly *is*

Comment: i know its a pretty poor design i am just trying to do this as a practice @Strawberry

Comment: That's great. So practice improving your schema; that's the real skill.

Comment: hum, in that case how would i structure it better, value1, value2, value3 are supposed to be the product name, and the numbers belows are the stock level. basically i was thinking taking the first row as the baed level, and subtact evreything to get a currect number

Comment: You'd have separate table for stock ( product_id, quantity)

Comment: what about keeping track of them, for quantity if i updates everytime i get a sale it would be fine to check the current stock, but I would want to be able to check the previous day stock as well, like the end of day stock level for let says 10 days back

Comment: You'd have a third column

Comment: to store each day's value? i wanna be able to check the selected date stock level at any time

Comment: It would be a date column

Comment: @KarsonYip you'd want at least two tables, something like a `products` table with a `product_id`, and a `product_transactions` table with `product_id`, `qty_change`, and `trans_when`. A positive qty_change could represent a shipment received, a negative one would represent sales or other stock decreases. Then to get stock levels at various times you'd just SUM qty_change where trans_when < sometime. This could be expanded further with transaction types, staff responsible for the change, etc..., but those two are the core idea.

Answer (score 0):

With conditional aggregation you can just do something like this:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END * value1)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,  for this, you can calculate the sum of value1, but what if there are like 150 columns like i said, i cant do 150 of this, is there any ways i can do it when there is n amount of columns?

Comment: As others have already said, if you have 150 columns like this, you likely have a problem with your database design. If you end up on a preexisting project like that, the only way to handle that is by handling each column separately.

Answer (score 0):

A normalised schema might look somewhat as follows:

```
index product stock
    1 value1    100 
    2 value1      6    
    3 value1     23   

    1 value2    200
    2 value2     30  
    3 value2     11  

    1 value3    300  
    2 value3     12  
    3 value3     22
```

Attempting to continue with the existing schema is... well, decorum prohibits further comment.